# how parse tag xml from <xxxEND TO </xxx> in AIX sed

Tags: xml, parsing, sed, tags, aix

I am new in aix and I need your support, in a file there are many tags that arrive in the following way:

```
<xxxBEGIN
        DATA
<xxxEND
```

Where xxx is a variable word of length.

which is needed from the following result:

```
<xxx>
    DATA
</xxx>
```

The problem is with the END tag.

```
sed 's/BEGIN/>/g' file.txt > file_v2.txt (correct)
sed 's/END^/'</'/g' file.txt > file_v2.txt (incorrect)
```

your help please.

Comment: can you be more specific with your problem?

Comment: Hi Danilo,
I tell you that I have a 500mb text file that contains supposed xml tags with the words (BEGIN / END).
My intention is to replace those words to give XML tag's form this in order to read the file with Informatica Powercenter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the word in front of END, capture it and add the forward slash before it in the output.

```
sed 's/\(\w\+\)END/\/\1>/g'
```

A slightly more robust solution for both BEGIN and END would be:

```
sed 's/^\(<\w\+\)BEGIN/\1>/g'
sed 's/^<\(\w\+\)END/<\/\1>/g'
```

Which will ensure only lines starting with '<' are picked up.

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for your prompt response.
I tried the code for the END and it does not solve what I can be doing wrong?

Comment: [usr@srvprodpwc] /tmp/temp> echo '<xxxEND' | sed 's/^<\(\w\+\)END/<\/\1>/g'  RESPONSE: <xxxEND

Comment: You need to escape the brackets like so `\(\w\+\)` this is the capture group being called by `\1`. Without escaping you are searching for the brackets.